# Applying for PayPal adaptive payments, filling the form

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

So the idea is simple, the product is sort of a marketplace.

Main Flow

- Sellers put stuff for sale
- Buyers place order requests (application created preapproval on PP)
- Seller approves order request (transaction happens and application receives the money)
- Seller fulfils order request

  - Buyer approves (money released to seller, a % cut is taken by the app)
  - Buyer complains within 48 hours (refund or a dispute which can end in refund or no refund)

Pretty much technically we have it covered by PayPal's API, the problem is filling out the form on apps.paypal.com.

So, the questions I have are for the following sections of the form.

**Services used by app**

*Adaptive Accounts*

- What are adaprive accounts? Is this for the app, sellers, or buyers?

*3rd Party Permissions - 
Request users grant you permission to make API calls on their behalf.*

- Are these permissions for the app? Or for some 3rd party apps, running under our app?
- If it's for the main app, why's it called 3rd party?

*Testing Information*

- How thorough and detailed does it need to be?
- From the perspective of seller, buyer, or both?
- How can I give them scenarios when we have different gateway now, and hence different workflow than what we want to achieve with PayPal? Or do I have to give them the staging site, after we've done the sandbox PayPal implementation?
- Do they want staging or do they want to make purchases on production? Staging might be off here and there.

**Any other advice**

If you've been through the process yourself, please share your experiences, highs and lows.

Answer (score 1):

Here are good instructions on filling out the paypal form and getting approved to use adaptive payments: http://www.chainedpayments.com/EZChain/SubmitAppToPayPal.html